# Split a MYSSQL Field & Insert into another table using trigger

Tags: mysql, triggers

When an insert happens into a certain MYSQL table, I need to split a particualar field into two and insert into another table.   The field is a set of coordinates.  In the source table they are stored as one: 52.52001,13.40495    in the destination table, they are stored as two fields:  52.52001 and 13.40495

I am happy with setting up a trigger that takes an entry from one table and inserts into the other, what I don't know how to do is split the coordinates field in two (removing the comma too) and insert into two columns in the other table.  Not even sure this is possible as part of a trigger.

Any advice please?

thank you.
Pete

I have looked at using substring_index, but I don't fully understand how to use it within a trigger.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
CREATE TRIGGER tr
AFTER INSERT ON table1
FOR EACH ROW

/* variant 1 - update existing row
UPDATE table2 SET column21 = SUBSTRING_INDEX(NEW.column11, ',', 1),
                  column22 = SUBSTRING_INDEX(NEW.column11, ',', -1)
WHERE id = NEW.id */

/* variant 2 - insert new row
INSERT INTO table2 (column21, column22, id)
VALUES (SUBSTRING_INDEX(NEW.column11, ',', 1), 
        SUBSTRING_INDEX(NEW.column11, ',', -1), 
        NEW.id) */
;
```